# NodeJS taking too much time in making http/https request

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, microservices, latency

we are facing a common issue where making an api call to external microservice, takes a-lot of time  to dispatch from microservice, it can even take minutes

- We are facing this issue in all the microservices in nodeJS
- Below is the image which represents, the CPU was idle for 7.14 seconds and process actually completed in 4.3ms
- we tried using latest version of axios, node-fetch but did'nt have any better results
- we added keep alive agents but it didnt help us either

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The http request is always fast, so the problem is in your server.
Check what happened in your server and try to split your code. One request, for specific use only and not many uses, can be a good start.